# Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: centos, software-installation, php, command, sqlserver

I'm using web server nginx, php 7.1 fpm and laravel in Centos 7.
I want to install SQL Server following [the official installation tutorial for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017) but I'm confused with this command:

```
echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/pdo_sqlsrv.ini

echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/sqlsrv.ini
```

What does it even mean? I tried to understand it write `extension=sqlsrv.so` then `>>` to `php --ini` (this means php.ini right?)

Then I tried to use this `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files"` and produce "Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d"
now I'm confused with the sed command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer myself. It turns out, I can do command `echo` or `curl` using sudo if using `bash -c` like this :

```
sudo bash -c 'echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> "$(php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||")/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"'
```

thank you for anyone who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The command is used to get the path to the directory of your additional php configuration files to create new `*.ini` files.

If I run the command `php --ini` it lists my configuration files and paths like this:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
...
```

You can see the line `Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d`. The `grep` is used to get this specific line and the `sed` command is used to strip off `Scan for additional .ini files in:` and leave the path to the config directory `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d`.

So the first command appends the string `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` to file `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini` and in your case the path is `/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini`.

Comment: thankyou for the explanation. now i understand the meaning of echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files"

what about sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/pdo_sqlsrv.ini ? still not understand this part. thanks before

Answer (score 0):

The back ticks are sort of equivalent to `$()`, but harder to use. In this case they are equivalent. So the code can read as.

```
echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> "$(php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||")/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"

echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> "$(php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||")/sqlsrv.ini"
```

For each line, the bit in the `$()` is run first, and the output (stdout) is substituted in its place. The whole line is then re-scanned and run again.

Therefore the bit in the `$()` is used to create the directory name, and the text `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` (for the first one) is appended to `«directory»/pdo_sqlsrv.ini`

I have refactored as (not tested as I don't intend to install php). Hope it makes sense now.

```
directory="$(php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||")"

echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> "${directory}/pdo_sqlsrv.ini" 
echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> "${directory}/sqlsrv.ini"
```

Comment: i see that you made it as an environment variable right ? i will try it your way since i need to create a script for this without login as root 1st. (echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/pdo_sqlsrv.ini) the command cannot use sudo and produce error : permission denied

Comment: Yes but not an environment variable. It i just a variable.